# How can I quickly display complex data on a asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, data-binding

How should one display complex data objects in a asp.net page? Actually the below class is read only, the data needs to be displayed on screen so that agent's can tell customers how much they have to pay. I don't want to write lot of code to normalize it and show it on the page. This data is returned by web service method call.

```
public class FeeInfo {

private string countryInfoTextField;
public string CountryInfoTextField
{
    get{return this.countryInfoTextField;}
    set{this.countryInfoTextField= value;}
}
private stringfeeInfoTextField;
public string FeeInfoTextField
{
    get{return this.feeInfoTextField;}
    set{this.feeInfoTextField= value;}
}
private string taxInfoTextField;
public string TaxInfoTextField
{
    get{return this.taxInfoTextField;}
    set{this.taxInfoTextField = value;}
}

private string additionalInfoTextField;
public string additionalInfoText
{
    get{return this.additionalInfoTextField;}
    set{this.additionalInfoTextField = value;}
}

private PromotionInfo[] promotionInfoField; //Class

private SendAmountInfo sendAmountsField; //Class

private EstimatedReceiveAmountInfo receiveAmountsField; //Class

/// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("promotionInfo")]
        public PromotionInfo[] promotionInfo {
            get {
                return this.promotionInfoField;
            }
            set {
                this.promotionInfoField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public SendAmountInfo sendAmounts {
            get {
                return this.sendAmountsField;
            }
            set {
                this.sendAmountsField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public EstimatedReceiveAmountInfo receiveAmounts {
            get {
                return this.receiveAmountsField;
            }
            set {
                this.receiveAmountsField = value;
            }
        }
}
```

I converted the above into a list and bound it to gridview, but all I see is the 4 fields, not the last 3 complex properties. What could be the fast and quick way to show this data on screen?

Comment: the last three are private variables.They're not going to be exposed outside the class.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh those variable have 3 public properties too, just like the other variables. Sorry, I missed that while pasting the code here. Just updated the code.

Answer (score -1):

add a toList method to FeeInfo.

```
public List<FeeInfo> toList(){
    var retList;
    var props = this.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach(var prop in props) {
        if(prop.propertyType.IsArray) 
            for(int i=0;i<prop.length;i++) 
                 retList.add(new GridView(prop.GetValue[i]);
        else if(prop.propertyType.isClass) 
            retList.Add(new Gridview(prop.GetValue()));
        else retList.Add(prop.GetValue());
    }
    return retList;
}
```

dont have VS to test atm unfortunatly so there's probably some adjustments to make :)

Comment: Indeed, several adjustments would be required in order to make this even compile. Let alone converting the Java-like construction to generally advisable C# conventions.

Comment: im more interested in the advisable conventions. made it look better. VS Community is installing since idk when i'll get my new work laptop.

Comment: @Narcil FeeInfo is returned by web service method, if I change the reference.cs file, every time I updated the reference, any changes that I made will be lost.